# Find all occurrences of regex pattern in string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code:

```
var varFormula = "IIF(ABCCF012HIZ3000=0,0,ABCCF012HCZ3000/ABCCF012HIZ3000)"
MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(varFormula, @"^AB([CC|DD|EE]+[F|G])[0-9]{3}(HI|IC|HC)Z[A-Z0-9]{4}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

From above, I want to extract the following from `varFormula` but I'm not able to get any matches/groups:

```
ABCCF012HCZ3000
ABCCF012HIZ3000
```

Comment: Just remove **^** at the beginning and **$** at the end of the regex

Comment: You can omit the anchors, and use a grouping for the CC etc.. `\bAB(?:CC|DD|EE)[FG][0-9]{3}(?:HI|[IH]C)Z[A-Z0-9]{4}\b` https://regex101.com/r/DIdLBR/1

Comment: @NikitaChayka Thank you for your comment. I have removed the ^ and $ and it is now working.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you for your comment. I have removed the ^ and $ and it is now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex uses ^ and $ which designate the start and end of a line. So it will never match the varFormula. Try the following:

```
var varFormula = @"IIF(ABCCF012HIZ3000=0,0,ABCCF012HCZ3000/ABCCF012HIZ3000)";
MatchCollection match = Regex.Matches(varFormula, @"AB(?:[CC|DD|EE]+[F|G])[0-9]{3}(?:HI|IC|HC)Z[A-Z0-9]{4}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Should give you three matches:

```
Match 1 ABCCF012HIZ3000
Match 2 ABCCF012HCZ3000
Match 3 ABCCF012HIZ3000
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have removed the ^ and $ and it is now working.